# writing cocos2d code for both iphone 4s and iphone 5

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I know cocos2d can take into consideration whether code is run on iphone or ipad using

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)    {

}
```

But can I write cocos2d code takes into consideration both sizes of the iphone screen. For Example:

```
#define xPosition1 120.0
#define xPosition2 240.0
#define xPosition3 360.0

if (iphone5) {
        #define xPosition1 142.0
        #define xPosition2 284.0
        #define xPosition3 426.0
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use the following:

```
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;
```

This will return you the screen width and height depending on your device. That means, the iPhone 4S will return 320 x 480 and iPhone 5 will return 320 x 568